# Global Variables no longer initialized when scrolling a dynamic TableView (iOS)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView being populated with an NSArray. Unfortunately this array is constantly changing size and contents. So I want to create a global single copy of that array (at one point in time) and use it to populate my table.

This is what I'm doing:

.h

```
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController {
//    ProcessListArrayHolder *processListArrayObject;

    NSArray *_myArray;
}

...

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray *myArray;
```

.m

```
@synthesize myArray = _myArray;

// in ViewDidLoad
_myArray = [myObject myFunctionThatReturnsAnArray]; //This function returns a different array every time because the data is constantly changing
```

However, when I scroll, it looks like _myArray is empty, and I get a "Bad Access" trying to get a value from it.

What is the TableView doing when I scroll? 
Is there any way to make it load the entire table in one go?

**Edit:** To fix this, I just worked with the property, "myArray", calling it as "self.myArray", and ignored _myArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should probably be using the generated setter (that's what it's there for)

```
self.myArray = [myObject myFunctionThatReturnsAnArray];
```

Where do you initialize that array in the first place?

What does your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfRowsInSection` code look like? If you have a properly initialized array and properly set up delegate functions, you should never receive a bad access. As you scroll, the table view is using its delegates to populate and display just the cells it needs at the time.

Comment: Accessing self.myArray instead of using _myArray, and shifting around a few things seemed to do the trick!